# Increase readability to assert IsNotNullOrEmpty with constraint-based asserts

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm currently rewriting some unit tests to use NUnit 3 instead of NUnit 2 and need to change some asserts to contraint-based asserts. I have the following asserts:

```
Assert.IsNullOrEmpty(result);
```

That I've changed to:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.Null.Or.Empty);
```

However, I'm not totally pleased with the readability when asserting `IsNotNullOrEmpty`:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty);
```

My current suggestion is to create the following static class:

```
public static class Text
{
    public static EmptyConstraint IsNullOrEmpty => Is.Null.Or.Empty;

    public static EmptyConstraint IsNotNullOrEmpty => Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty;
}
```

Usage:

```
Assert.That(result, Text.IsNotNullOrEmpty);
```

This offers better readability at the expense of introducing a custom constraint. Is there a standard way of making the same assertion, or should I continue using `Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty` instead?

Comment: This question can be answered objectively. Edited the body to restate the question in non-subjective terms; voting to re-open.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your assertion for `Is.Null.Or.Empty` reads perfectly fine without a `Test` class. Moreover, when this assertion fails, you know exactly what happened: you've got a valid `string` object that is not empty.

The issues I see with "DeMorgan-ized" version of its negation, i.e. `Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty`, are that it is too long, and it does not read nearly as nicely as `Is.Null.Or.Empty` does.

However, rather than making a separate constraint for it, I would assert its parts separately, i.e.

```
Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Empty);
```

The reason I would do it like that is that the two failure conditions do not overlap, i.e. `result` could be `null`, or it could be empty, but it cannot be both at the same time. A single compound assertion does not distinguish between these two situations, so you end up going for a debugger to see whether `result` was `null` or empty.

Separate assertions, on the other hand, tell you exactly what happens while remaining very readable. They "cost" you one extra line per assertion; I think this is a reasonable cost for getting more precise information about potential failures.